# Finding Anchor and Reference Point of a Cube Root Function.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

My brother sent me a question from his Pre-Calculus Study Guide. I have been studying math for $4$ years and don't ever recall seeing a question like this.

The question:

Graph $f(x) = (-1/2)(x+1)^{1/3} - 2$ on the axis provided. You must include the anchor and reference point to receive full credit.

Any advice on how to approach would be appreciated.

Comment: What do "anchor" and "reference point" mean?

Comment: The reference point of say the xy plane is (0,0).
Not sure about the anchor point though.

Comment: Anything on how to solve?

Answer (score 1):

First plot
$x^{1/3}$.
It goes through the origin.

The change to
$(x+1)^{1/3}$
moves it $1$ to the left
so it goes through
$(-1, 0)$.

The change to
$-\frac12(x+1)^{1/3}$
turns it upside-down
and compresses is vertically
by a factor of $2$.

The final change to
$-\frac12(x+1)^{1/3}-2$
moves it down by 2.

And that's the way it is.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
I am aware of how to do transformations, just need to know how to find the reference and anchor points.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by those.

Comment: Confused too. I am hoping David above could guide me through it.

Answer (score 0):

In my son's textbook, it says for the general parent equation, $$f(x)=a\sqrt[3]{x-h} + k$$ the reference point is (1,1) which is equal to (1 + h, a + k).  It's a quicker way maybe to solve for the inflection point $(h,k)$ and $a$.

So for equation $$f(x)=\sqrt[3](x)$$ the reference point is (1,1) and $h=0$, $k=0$ and $a=1$

Comment: Use LaTeX, please: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/

Comment: LaTeX incorporated.  Thanks